# How generate checkerboard with Octave?

Tags: octave

I need to generate a checkerboard black/white with Octave.
I want use this virtual image for conversion cartesian to polar or perspective projections.
Anyone can show a script? Thanks

I've tried this:

```
clear all
close all
clc

img = magic(16);

%# convert coordinates from cartesian to polar
[r c] = size(img);
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:c,1:r);
[theta rho] = cart2pol(X, Y);

figure
subplot(121), image(img), axis square

colormap(gray(256))

subplot(122), surf(theta, rho,img),axis square;
view(0,90)
```

Comment: what is your solution so far?

Comment: Posting "do my work for me" questions that are open ended and 'localized' (meaning only useful for you) are generally not answered, and are down-voted.  When you have over 1000 reputation, the legions of hackers, me included, will be more inclined to do something that might fit your specifications.  The best way to get reputation to is to answer other people's questions and receive up votes for them.

Answer (score 2):

this does what the OP was looking for.  But this question was asked months ago!

slight modification to OP's code.

```
clear all
close all
clc
%my changes start
img = zeros(8,8);
img(1:2:end,1:2:end)=255;
img(2:2:end,2:2:end)=255;
%my changes end

%# convert coordinates from cartesian to polar
[r c] = size(img);
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:c,1:r);
[theta rho] = cart2pol(X, Y);

figure
subplot(121), image(img), axis square

colormap(gray(256))

subplot(122), surf(theta, rho,img),axis square;
view(0,90)
```